# Cutting character values according to value from file

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the which i am doing

```
import csv
output = open('output.txt' , 'wb')


# this functions return the min for num.txt
def get_min(num):
    return int(open('%s.txt' % num, 'r+').readlines()[0])

# temporary variables
last_line = ''
input_list = []

#iterate over input.txt in sort the input in a list of tuples 
for i, line in enumerate(open('input.txt', 'r+').readlines()): 
    if i%2 == 0: 
        last_line = line
    else:
        input_list.append((last_line, line))
filtered = [(header, data[:get_min(header[-2])] + '\n' ) for (header, data) in input_list]
[output.write(''.join(data)) for data in filtered]
output.close()
```

In this code `input.txt` is something like this

```
>012|013|0|3|M
AFDSFASDFASDFA
>005|5|67|0|6
ACCTCTGACC
>029|032|4|5|S
GGCAGGGAGCAGGCCTGTA
```

and `num.txt` is something like this

```
M 4
P 10
```

I want that in above `input.txt` check the amount of value from the `num.txt` by looking at its last column which is same like in `num.txt` and cut its character according to that values

I think the error in my code is that it only accept the integer text file , where it should also accept file which contain alphabets

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what should be the correct result? I have trouble understanding the 'cut its character according to that values' part. Can you add an example of correct output?

Comment: So (for example) you want to get the 394th match, or 394 counts, of the string `EOG6CC67M` in `input.txt`? I'm a bit confused too :P

Comment: @Allendar I want that it keep first 394 counts and delete remaining , i short that value to 4 for better and easy understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The totally revised version, after a long chat with the OP;

```
import os
import re

# Fetch all hashes and counts
file_c = open('num.txt')
file_c = file_c.read()
lines = re.findall(r'\w+\.txt \d+', file_c)
numbers = {}

for line in lines:
    line_split = line.split('.txt ')
    hash_name = line_split[0]
    count = line_split[1]

    numbers[hash_name] = count

#print(numbers)

# The input file
file_i = open('input.txt')
file_i = file_i.read()

for hash_name, count in numbers.iteritems():
    regex = '(' + hash_name.strip() + ')'
    result = re.findall(r'>.*\|(' + regex + ')(.*?)>', file_i, re.S)

    if len(result) > 0:
        data_original = result[0][2]
        stripped_data = result[0][2][int(count):]

        file_i = file_i.replace(data_original, '\n' + stripped_data)

        #print(data_original)
        #print(stripped_data)

#print(file_i)


# Write the input file to new input_new.txt
f = open('input_new.txt', 'wt')
f.write(file_i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so;

```
import re

min_count = 4 # this variable will contain that count integer from where to start removing
str_to_match = 'EOG6CC67M' # this variable will contain the filename you read

input = '' # The file input (input.txt) will go in here

counter = 0

def callback_f(e):
    global min_count
    global counter
    counter += 1
    # Check your input
    print(str(counter) + ' >>> ' + e.group())

    # Only replace the value with nothing (remove it) after a certain count
    if counter > min_count:
        return '' # replace with nothing

result = re.sub(r''+str_to_match, callback_f, input)
```

With this tactic you can keep count with a global counter and there's no need to do hard line-loops with complex structures.

**Update**

More detailed version with file access;

```
import os
import re

def callback_f(e):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    # Check your input
    print(str(counter) + ' >>> ' + e.group())


# Fetch all hash-file names and their content (count)
num_files = os.listdir('./num_files')
numbers = {}

for file in num_files:
    if file[0] != '.':
        file_c = open('./num_files/' + file)
        file_c = file_c.read()

        numbers[file.split('.')[0]] = file_c


# Now the CSV files
csv_files = os.listdir('./csv_files')

for file in csv_files:
    if file[0] != '.':
        for hash_name, min_count in numbers.iteritems():
            file_c = open('./csv_files/' + file)
            file_c = file_c.read()

            counter = 0

            result = re.sub(r''+hash_name, callback_f, file_c)

            # Write the replaced content back to the file here
```

Considered directory/file structure;

```
 + Projects
   + Project_folder
     + csv_files
       - input1.csv
       - input2.csv
       ~ etc.
     + num_files
       - EOG6CC67M.txt
       - EOG62JQZP.txt
       ~ etc.
     - python_file.py
```

- The CSV files contain the big chunks of text you state in your original question.
- The Num files contain the hash-files with an Integer in them

What happens in this script;

1. Collect all Hash files (in a dictionary) and it's inner count number
2. Loop through all CSV files
3. Subloop through the collected numbers for each CSV file
4. Replace/remove (based on what you do in `callback_f()`) hashes after a certain count
5. Write the output back (it's the last comment in the script, would contain the `file.write()` functionality)

Comment: There are 100 of txt files , not just 1 , thats y file handling is used

Comment: Seriously? You can just loop this structure on each file. I didn't assume I needed to bake everything for you :P You don't need file-line handling for this problem. Just read the whole files into a string variable.

Comment: `str_to_match = 'EOG6CC67M'` its focus is only on this , i treated it as input.txt

Comment: Yes, so you read it into that variable dynamically by opening the file and read it's contents in there. If the content is different. You need to do some checks on it before you put it in the variable. I don't see the problem here :)

Comment: I've updated the answer. The only assumption I did here is the paths (`num_files ` and `csv_files`). And I left the write-back to the file out, to not let you accidentally damage your originals.

Comment: `file_c = open('C:\S_Project\New_folder\num.txt' + file)
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'C:\\S_Project\\New_folder\num.txtEOG6003Q5.txt.txt'`

Comment: Are your files separated in both subfolders? `New_folder` would be the root (where the python file is). Subfolders would be `/num_files/` and `/csv_files/`. You really should check what's in the error messages. You can debug that yourself to be honest. The point of my script is that all `EOG6003Q5.txt` (etc) files are in `/num_files/` and all `input.csv` (etc) files are in `/csv_files/`. You seem to have mingled with the script. `EOG6003Q5.txt.txt` is impossible to arise if you would've only changed the subfolder names. You probably need to replace `/` with \ for Windows path-separators.

Comment: as i mention in my question that input.txt is the txtfile not directory and num.txt is a txt file not directory , i have to work only on 2 text files

Comment: I understand that. I'm just saying the files would be in those folders, to separate them. You just mentioned you have hundreds of files. If you are not clear enough on what you want you get these kind of confusions.

Comment: Look there are two options for me , 1st is that i split `num.txt` into number of txt files with their data and than used them with `input.txt` which i did with my code which i mentioned above , and the other and good option is that i shouldn't split num.txt and just play with these two files and get my result

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm totally lost. I've updated the answer telling how my file- and directory structure looks like and what the files contain. I really have no idea how to help you because I can't seem to understand what you want :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27978/discussion-between-angel-and-allendar)

Comment: @Allender +1 for your help